# Is it possible to get the variable defined in the perl file to the pm file?

Tags: perl

### test.pm

```
package test;
use Exporter;

our @ISA=qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT=qw(version);

sub show(){
 print $var;
}
sub version()
{
        $out=`uname`;
        return $out;
}
```

### test.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

BEGIN{
use lib qw(./Module);
}
use test;

our $var="what to print?";
$out=version();
print $out;
```

## Output :

Linux

```
print $var; //prints nothing, Can pass variable in both ways
```

I thought `$var` will be global and can be seen there also.
If i consider the package it is still not available as 
`$main::var` in package test

Can you please tell why?

Comment: you dont even call show.. so how do you think print $var will even be executed?

Comment: While you are at it, why don't you pick a proper user name, that way you become part of the SO community rather than being quasi-anonymous.

Answer (score 3):

Usually you would pass data as parameter to the function of the module.

in test.pm:

```
sub show {
    my $var = shift;
    print $var;
}
```

in test.pl:

```
use test;

show('test123');
```

this would print test123.